# Error occured in nested sub-schema collections using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I need a nested subschema having ids so i tried the below code but data cant inserted 
code 
  My model..

```
 var connection= handler.getConnection();
console.log(connection);
autoIncrement.initialize(connection);

var subSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    course_Submodule: [{
        type: String,
        required: true, 

    }]
},{ _id : false });
subSchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, {
    model: 'Submodule',
    field: 'Id_submodule',
    startAt: 1,
    incrementBy: 1
});

var courseSchema = new Schema({
    course_Name: String,
    course_Code: String,
    course_Submodule: [subSchema],
    course_Author: String,
    id_subject: String,
    id_user: String,
});

courseSchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, {
    model: 'Course',
    field: 'Id_course',
    startAt: 1,
    incrementBy: 1
});
var Course = connection.model('Course', courseSchema);
var Submodule = connection.model('Submodule', subSchema);
module.exports = Course;
```

bt in db data is inserted like this

```
"_id" : ObjectId("578efe6da667fff80d09d5ed"),
    "Id_course" : 214,
    "course_Name" : "chemistry1",
    "course_Code" : "ch1",
    "course_Author" : "David",
    "id_subject" : "3",
    "course_Submodule" : [
        {
            "Id_submodule" : 14,
            "course_Submodule" : [ ]
        },
        {
            "Id_submodule" : 15,
            "course_Submodule" : [ ]
        }
    ],

    "__v" : 0
```

trying these code i cant insert the value of course_Submodule.Is ther any anotherway for this .help me please

Comment: If you want result of other schema into your existing schema, you need not copy the items but can only store its objectID and can populate the object while fetching from DB. If you want i can provide you with a quick example of how to implement this.

Comment: i want to store the submodule like this {
    _id: "mainId"
    subdocArray: [
      {
        _id: "unwantedId",
        field: "value"
      },
      {
        _id: "unwantedId",
        field: "value"
      }
    ]
}

Comment: yes i want thal code @AjitejKaushik

Comment: The way you want to store, i havent executed anything like that but i can provide a small example of what i have stated in my comment!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of duplicating the data, you can simply store the object id of the other object into your schema.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//Schema for doctors
var StudentSchema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    user : {
        type : Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',     //i have a different model User
        required : true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Student', StudentSchema);
```

Your query over student schema can look like this

```
db.collection.find(//condition, function(err, data){
         //your functionality
})
.populate('User', 'dob')
.exec();
```

My user schema has a field `dob`.

This is a small and tidy example to avoid duplicacy of data.

Hope it will help.